# Sending and receiving data in Xml format via Ajax jquery

Tags: c#, .net, database

I wont to send data from textarea with Ajax in XML format, and to receive data in XML format. I also wont to know how to catch data on server side(PHP) and how to send data to client.

Client side code:

'str' is a variable with value from textarea

```
function sendValue(str){
// Fire off AJAX request.       
$.ajax(
    {
        // Define AJAX properties.
        url: "transliterate.php",
        type: "post",               
        data: { sendValue: str },
        dataType: "json",


        // Define the success method.
        success: function(data){
            data.returnValue = data.returnValue.replace(/\n/g,'<br/>');
            $('#result_box').html(data.returnValue);
            if(data.returnValue.length <= 50) {
                $('#result_box').addClass('short_text');
            }else{
                $('#result_box').removeClass('short_text');
            }
        },


        // Define the error method.
        error: function( objAJAXRequest, strError ){
            $( "#response" ).text(
                "Error! Type: " +
                strError
                );
        }
});
```

};

This is server-side code:

```
<?php 

//Get Post Variables. The name is the same as 
//what was in the object that was sent in the jQuery
if (isset($_POST['sendValue'])){
    $value = $_POST['sendValue'];   
}else{
    $value = "";
}

//Because we want to use json, we have to place things in an array and encode it for json.
//This will give us a nice javascript object on the front side.
echo json_encode(array("returnValue"=>$value));

?>
```

This works for me when data type is json, but how can I do the same thing with XML?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify in your AJAX request that the response will be XML:

```
dataType: "xml"
```

Then the argument passed to your `success` callback will represent the DOM of this XML that you could manipulate directly. By the way it's considered good practice to specify the HTTP Content-Type response header on your server. So for example if you intend to rerun XML from your script make sure you have set the proper header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

In this case you don't even need the `dataType` parameter for the AJAX request. jQuery will automatically deduce it from the Content-Type response header and parse the result that is passed to the `success` callback accordingly.

Comment: Can you write a code. I tried what you said, but somehing's wrong. My page in browser has changed the face and nothing is returned in second textarea.